# Video Playback Issue on iOS Devices with next-videos Package in Next.js Web Application

Tags: typescript, next.js, frontend, next.js13

I am using the next-videos package to incorporate a video tag into your Next.js web application. While this solution functions successfully on laptops and Android devices, it encounters difficulties on iPhones. The video fails to play as expected on iOS devices.[IOS device image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kUnm.jpg)

The video source is correct and works well in laptop and android devices

Code:-
import Link from "next/link";

const Hero = () => {
return (



#1 IN REVERSE ETL

Get fresh, accurate customer data in all your tools - fast


Hightouch syncs your data to CRM, e-mail, advertising tools and
more. No engineering, manual work, or costly CDP required.

```
      <div>
        <input
          className="pl-3 border-none outline-none text-black w-full md:hidden"
          placeholder="Work Email"
        ></input>
      </div>

      <div className="flex gap-4 ">
        <button className="text-black p-2 rounded-md shadow-sm  bg-[#C5EA41] hover:bg-[#C5EA41e3] w-full sm:w-auto">
          Book Demo
        </button>
        <div className="text-white grid grid-cols-2 gap-1 hover:gap-2 items-center">
          <span className="text-lg hidden lg:block">
            <Link href="" className="hover:underline" color={"white"}>
              {"Getting Started"}
            </Link>
          </span>

          <span className="text-lg hidden lg:block">{">"}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <video
      src={require("../public/heroFilm.webm")}
      autoPlay
      muted
      loop
      className="responsive-video "
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

);
};

export default Hero;

I am expecting [Android Browser image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4pom.jpg)